# My Typo3 Repository findByUid returns always NULL in a Scheduler Task

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-11.x

I am creating a extbase typo3 11.5 extension, that updates jobs in a database with a Scheduler Task `ImportJobsTask`.

```
namespace MyCompany\MyExtension\Task;

class ImportJobsTask extends AbstractTask
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->jobOfferRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(JobOfferRepository::class);
        $job = ['id' => 253, 'title' => 'Lagermitarbeiter'];
        $job = $this->jobOfferRepository->findByJob($job);
        DebuggerUtility::var_dump($job);
        return true;
    }
}
```

For that i use a `JobsOfferRepository`.

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyCompany\MyExtension\Domain\Repository;

class JobOfferRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository
{
    public function findByJob(array $job)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();

        $constraints = [
            $query->equals('job_id', $job["id"]),
            $query->equals('job_title', $job["title"]),
        ];
        $query->matching($query->logicalAnd($constraints));
        return $query->execute()->getFirst();
    }
}
```

In this Repository i call from the Model `JobOffers` the functions `updateJob($job_id)` and `createJob($job)` for updating and creating such Jobs, these works fine.

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyCompany\MyExtension\Domain\Model;

class JobOffer extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity
{
    public function createJob(array $job, int $pid): JobOffer
    {
        $newJob = new self();
        $newJob->setPid($pid);
        $newJob->setJobId($job["id"]);
        $newJob->setJobTitle($job["title"]);
        # some code...
        return $newJob;
}
```

But in my Task i just can't get any results from `findByJob($job)`, it always returns `NULL`. Everything i try to get some jobs from inside of my Repository always returns `NULL`.
On the other hand i can store new Jobs from the Repository, if i call `$jobOffer->createJob($job)` from there.

I implemented a setPid() function in the Repository to make sure the `storagePid` is correct, but the result didn't change.

Somebody has an idea, what i might be missing? Some configuration? Messed up Namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found my answer.

i implemented a function `setPID($pids)` in my Repository, than everything worked. The other problems were from bad testing.

in my Task's `execute()`:

```
...
$this->storagePid = $typoscript['module.']['tx_myextension_web_myextensionjobadmin.']['persistence.']['storagePid'];

$jobOfferRepository = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(JobOfferRepository::class);
$jobOfferRepository->setPID(array($this->storagePid));
...
```

In my Repository:

```
    public function setPID($pids)
    {
        $querySettings = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Typo3QuerySettings::class);
        $querySettings->setStoragePageIds($pids);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);
    }
```

That was all i needed.
I guess the debugging part would have worked with Garvin's answer, too. But maybe my testing was so off that i didnt realize. i tried with `var_dump` instead of `DebuggerUtility::var_dump($object)` and got out of memory, which i misinterpreted.
yes, i am a typo3 beginner :-)

Answer (score 2):

Did you add defaultQuerySettings in your Repository to set/remove specific Restraints?

Or try a Debug on the created query to see if maybe some conditions mismatch?

An example repository setup could be:

```
<?php
namespace Faktore\Dummy\Domain\Repository;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\QuerySettingsInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings;
class DummyRepository extends Repository
{
    /**
     * initialize repository settings
     */
    public function initializeObject() {
        /** @var QuerySettingsInterface $defaultQuerySettings */
        $defaultQuerySettings = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Typo3QuerySettings::class);
        // remove the pid constraint
        $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
        $this->setDefaultQuerySettings($defaultQuerySettings);
    }

}
```

Comment: Addendum: If you want to access a just-created entity, you must first call the persistenceManager to really write the entity to databse.

Comment: no. these are in my db already. but well, maybe i am stupid... i have a uid=1 in my database, but it is ""deleted", so i only got NULL there. with a not deleted uid i get a result... findAll() still is empty though. i will adjust my question to reflect this.

Comment: Garvin: On my way to implement the setPid() function in the repository I tried that, too. it didnt change anything.

Comment: thank you, your answer would've been helpful, but i was too inexperienced to use it right i guess. i upvoted it at least

Comment: Hey there! No worries, we've all started somewhere. Sorry I didn't get notifications to your replies, else I would've tried to help some more. Great you got it working!